# When does this Bitwise expression evaluate to true?

Tags: bit-manipulation

When does `(i-3)&3` evaluate to true?
I found it here:
https://github.com/thewizard6296/SPOJ_CODE/blob/c03c5900b6a22389a3acf2ddf3ff76f230bcb358/CZ_PROB1.cpp

Comment: When `i - 3` isn't a multiple of 4

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers to your question. Accepting answer will give you +2 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what "3" is in 4-bit binary.

```
0011
```

For some number x, when is the expression "x & 3" true (i.e., non-zero)? It is true when x has 1s in either of its two least significant bit positions. When does a number not have 1s in either of its two least significant bit positions? Consider multiples of 4:

```
4:      8:      12:        etc...

  0011    0011     0011
& 0100  & 1000   & 1100
  ----    ----     ----
  0000    0000     0000
```

TL;DR (i - 3) & 3 evaluates to true when (i - 3) is not a multiple of 4.